# Complete Donation Report Per Donor

Tags: civicontribute

I am not familiar with the complete inner workings of CIVICRM - but does anyone know how to create a report (or CSV file) that would have the donor's information (name, address, etc) and their complete giving history? (date, amount of gift) for all gifts that have been entered?

Answer (score 2):

Try using Constituent Detail report(/civicrm/report/contact/detail?reset=1). This report gives Contact details along with other information like Contribution or Membership etc